# Obtener el nombre de un StoredProcedure en ejecución (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Lo que necesito es obtener el nombre del *Stored Procedure* en ejecución, almacenarlo en una variable e insertar un *log* en otra tabla para el registro, sin embargo, requiero que sea dinámico, es decir, no indicar el nombre directamente en un `varchar`.

Comment: que has intentado para hacer eso?

Comment: Sabía que se trataba de algo con con el nombre del objeto (OBJECT_NAME) o bien con la tabla de sistema SYS.Procedures, pero no de cómo obtenerlo. La respuesta de @Flxtr fue la adecuada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguente manera:

```
DECLARE @storedProcedureName VARCHAR(64)

SELECT @storedProcedureName = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
PRINT @storedProcedureName
```

Comment: Me fue útil, gracias.